# What is meant by "Group delay" in simple words?

Tags: group-delay

Although likes of this question have been asked many times on DSP SE

But i am unable to understand those and i wish to have a crystal clear explanation in simple words with example

The only thing that i am able to understand from those questions is that group delay is negative derivative of phase with respect to frequency. But what does negative derivative means here and why not positive derivative here?

Comment: The other similar questions explain quite well that it's a bit of a fuzzy world, but they do it with examples and clear words.

Comment: the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_delay_and_phase_delay) doesn't do a half bad job.  some people might be able to see fingerprints of someone's writing in it.

Comment: if people want, i can copy the introductory section from wikipedia to here and make it a legit answer.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Please do. :-)

Comment: as if i didn't have something better to do...  as a matter of fact...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my simplest explanation:

The group delay, as the negative derivative of phase, predicts the time delay of the amplitude envelope of a pulse, as shown in the hand-drawn graphic below. The upper part of the sketch shows a sinusoidal waveform varied in amplitude by its envelope. The lower one is showing this same envelope before and after a system that has group delay.

This applies when the phase of the frequency response can be approximated as linear for the "group" of frequencies within the pulse envelope. Thus for non-linear phase systems, this applies to generally narrower band signals such as the pulse I show where the amplitude transition is gradual.

Consider a single sine-wave with the amplitude envelope such as I show. The time delay of the sine wave itself would be predicted directly from the phase of the frequency response (by dividing by the frequency of the sine-wave: with $\phi = angle(H(j\omega))$,  the time delay is $-\phi(\omega)/\omega$), while the time delay of the pulse envelope is predicted from the negative derivative of the phase with respect to frequency ($-d\phi(\omega)/d\omega$)).

[image: Group Delay]

These posts and answers are helpful:

[Calculate the time delay introduced by group delay for IIR-Filters](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/65996/calculate-the-time-delay-introduced-by-group-delay-for-iir-filters/66001?noredirect=1#comment133688_66001)

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/135475/physical-significance-of-group-delay

And most helpful to what otherwise seems like a paradox of causality for positive group delay is this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/253463703_Causality_and_Negative_Group_Delays_in_a_Simple_Bandpass_Amplifier referenced by Max in this post [Physical Meaning of Negative Group Delay for causal LTI systems](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/47785/physical-meaning-of-negative-group-delay-for-causal-lti-systems) which I bottom line as causality is not violated but due to the bandwidth restrictions above we create a condition that causes the pulse envelope at the output to precede the input: The output pulse does not appear until the input amplitude varies (and if we have gain in the system the output envelope grows faster) and due to the bandwidth constraint and the result of destructive summation of the input pulse the output will start to decrease before the input does. Very cool DSP magic trick. See this [post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66574/negative-group-delay-and-envelope-advance/66593#66593) that illustrates this with a specific example.

Comment: I agree with this provided the bandwidth of interest is sufficiently small relative to the frequency of interest

Comment: Mr Boschen, I wasn’t referring to linear phase, mostly considering that given linear phase the group delay would be constant, and could just as well be called delay.  I worked out a derivation for group delay a while back, and my recollection is something like this: you define your input as a product of an envelope sinusoid and a carrier sinusoid.  The maths will give the delay of the envelope as the group delay equation so long as the amplitude response is uniform.  In general, this is always true as the bandwidth approaches zero.  It has been a while for me though.

Comment: So it may have been more appropriate for me to say: so long as the amplitude response is sufficiently uniform over the given bandwidth...

Comment: Even my last statement is a bit misleading, because it would seem incorrect for linear phase...  apologies, I don’t think I’m putting my thoughts to words effectively.  I was attempting to include non-linear phase more generally.

Comment: @DanSzabo See my update, I believe this may be closer to what you were getting at in our earlier conversation with regards to bandwidth.

Comment: which graph do you mean here in your answer,upward wave plot or bottom wave plot?"The group delay, as the negative derivative of phase, predicts the time delay of the amplitude envelope of a pulse, as shown in the hand-drawn graphic below''

Comment: @engr both plots. They are the same, the lower one is just the envelope of the top plot. It is the envelope itself that is delayed in time by the Group Delay, while the phase response predicts the delay of the sinusoidal waveform within the envelope. Make sense?

Comment: Please kindly elaborate your this sentence"Thus for non-linear phase systems, this applies to generally narrower band signals such as the pulse I show where the amplitude transition is gradual." I am confused here  how you say it holds for nonlinear phase systems??

Comment: @engr The point is that linear phase systems have a constant group delay, so in this case the time delay for the sinusoidal component is equally computed from the group delay and the phase response directly. For non-linear phase systems this does not apply.

Comment: ok thanks,one last query, are there any systems that produce zero G.D?

Comment: The simplest way to see this is consider a non-linear phase system where the phase starts going positive (due to a zero) then reaches two poles such that the phase reaches a maximum positive value and then starts to go negative. Right at the apex we would have 0 group delay yet a positive phase. So here the time delay of a pulsed waveform cannot be predicted from the phase but the phase does predict the phase shift between the input and output.

Comment: And I explain in the end of the response above how this does not violate causality even though we can have a case where the pulse envelope appears at the output before the input!!

Comment: What do you mean by pulse? Only one cycle or half cyle?or all cycles under one curved envelope as made by you?

Comment: @DSP_CS Sorry I missed your last comment (preface with "@DanBoschen" to ping me). By pulse I meant one curved envelope regardless what carrier frequency traces that out. My drawing above shows one "pulse".

Answer (score 6):

To understand group delay, it is first necessary to understand *phase delay* and *time delay*.

1. *Phase delay is the amount of phase lag a specific frequency
   experiences and has units of degrees.*
2. *Time delay is the amount of time lag a specific frequency
   experiences and has units of seconds.*

But there is an interesting relationship between phase delay (units = degrees) and time delay (units = seconds). Let me explain:

Say I have a 1Hz signal that goes through a filter and it experiences 90 degree phase delay. 90 degrees is 1/4 of a full 360 degree cycle. Thus for a 1Hz signal (which has 1 second period) the time delay experienced is 1 second / 4 = 0.25 seconds. Essentially the output lags the input by 0.25 seconds.

Now lets say I have a 2Hz signal. The 2Hz signal has a cycle period of 0.5 seconds. Let say I feed this signal through a filter and it also experiences 90 degree phase delay. Again, 90 degrees is 1/4 of a full 360 cycle. Thus for a 2hz signal, the time delay experienced is 0.5 second / 4 = 0.125 seconds. Now the output lags the input signal by 0.125 seconds.

**What this says is that constant phase delay does not equal constant time delay!**

Deriving the time delay from phase delay is dependent on the frequency itself. The only way for all frequencies to get delayed by the same time delay is if the phase lag increases as the frequency increases. More specifically, if the phase response is linear.

When the phase response is linear, we know all the frequencies get time delayed by the same amount. Thus if all frequencies are delayed the same amount, we have this notion of a "group" delay. Group refers to all frequencies.

The significance of group delay makes a lot more sense when looking at it visually.

If we feed an input signal into a filter with a group delay, all frequencies will be time delayed the same amount. Referring to the picture below, the outputted signal matches the input signal except it is slightly delayed.

[image]

If instead we fed that input signal into a filter that does not have a group delay (i.e. it's not linear phase). The frequencies will time delay different amounts resulting in an output signal that looks nothing like the inputted signal.

[image]

So even though each filter is low-pass, one filter distorts the signal such that it doesn't resemble the inputted signal. This is why linear-phase (constant group delay) filters are desirable in some applications.

**TLDR: When a system features a linear phase response, all frequencies lag by the same time delay. Since this time delay is the same for all frequencies, this delay is called "group delay" and has units of seconds.**

Comment: "Essentially the output lags the input by 0.25 seconds"What do you mean? Do you mean here that if in input we have peak at 0 second,then in output peak will occur at 0.25 second??

Comment: Correct. Visualize it like this: http://www.sengpielaudio.com/Sinusoidal%20Wave.gif

Comment: @engr I added some visuals which demonstrate the characteristics of constant group delay. And I fixed a couple typos.

Comment: what concept, you are trying to convey through the link in your comment  
                                                           
                 sengpielaudio.com/Sinusoidal%20Wave.gif

Comment: Your visuals are very nice. Can you also please include in your answer,nutshell definition of group delay in simple words?

Comment: *//If instead we fed that input signal into a filter with a non-constant group delay. ''* Hay, Izzo, the distortion you are showing in the figures below that sentence show distortion due to **non-constant phase delay**.  That distortion is specifically **not** about group delay.  But it is true that constant phase delay will coincide with constant group delay.  But when they are not constant, the two delays are not the same.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I removed the term "constant group delay" from my response because I don't like the term now that I read it back.

Comment: @Izzo, I don't think that you quite have the point.  There ***is*** a non-constant delay.  That means a different amount of delay for different frequencies.  But **group delay** applies to the **envelope** of the sinusoid, **not** to the **phase** of the sinusoid.  What you are demonstrating is the effect of a non-constant *phase* delay.  To show the effect of non-constant *group* delay, you need an envelope that is not a constant function.

Comment: please take a look at my answer, particularly this equation: $$ y(t) = \big| H(i \omega) \big| \ a(t - \tau_\text{g}) \cos \big( \omega (t - \tau_\phi) + \theta \big)$$

$\tau_\text{g}$ is the group delay and it is not inside the cosine function.

Comment: The statement "...into a filter that does not have a group delay (i.e. it's not linear phase). " is not quite accurate or misleading. It seems to suggest that a filter with non-linear phase doesn't have a group delay. However a non-linear phase filter has a group delay that varies over frequency. A linear phase filter has a constant group delay specifically.

Comment: @DanBoschen, thanks for response. For a filter that has non-linear phase, what would constitute "the group"? Since each frequency experiences a different delay, would there be a "group delay"?

Comment: @Izzo The "Group" is that group of frequencies. They travel together within the "Group Delay Variation" as a group, some leading and some lagging.  See figure 3-1 in this reference showing the group delay variation for a typical filter. https://scdn.rohde-schwarz.com/ur/pws/dl_downloads/dl_application/application_notes/1ef98/1EF98_1e.pdf (I down-voted to flag this, but if you concur and update I'll fix my vote).

Answer (score 3):

Group delay is a useful measure of time distortion, and is calculated by differentiating, with respect to frequency, the phase response of the device under test (DUT): the group delay is a measure of the slope of the phase response at any given frequency. Variations in group delay cause signal distortion, just as deviations from linear phase cause distortion.

In linear time-invariant (LTI) system theory, control theory, and in digital or analog signal processing, the relationship between the input signal, $x(t)$, to output signal, $y(t)$, of an LTI system is governed by a convolution operation:

$$y(t)  = (h*x)(t) \ \triangleq \ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(u) h(t-u) \, \mathrm{d}u $$

Or, in the frequency domain,

$$ Y(s) = H(s) X(s)  \, $$

where

$$ X(s)  =  \mathscr{L} \Big\{ x(t) \Big\} \ \triangleq \  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) e^{-st}\, \mathrm{d}t $$

$$ Y(s)  =  \mathscr{L} \Big\{ y(t) \Big\} \ \triangleq \  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y(t) e^{-st}\, \mathrm{d}t $$

and

$$ H(s)  =  \mathscr{L} \Big\{ h(t) \Big\} \ \triangleq \  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(t) e^{-st}\, \mathrm{d}t $$

Here $h(t)$ is the time-domain impulse response of the LTI system and $X(s)$, $Y(s)$, $H(s)$, are the Laplace transforms of the input $x(t)$, output $y(t)$, and impulse response $h(t)$, respectively.  $H(s)$ is called the *transfer function* of the LTI system and, like the impulse response $h(t)$, **fully** defines the input-output characteristics of the LTI system.

Suppose that such a system is driven by a quasi-sinusoidal signal, that is a sinusoid having an amplitude envelope $a(t)>0$ that is slowly changing relative to the frequency $\omega_0$ of the sinusoid. Mathematically, this means that the quasi-sinusoidal driving signal has the form

$$x(t) = a(t) \cos(\omega_0 t + \theta)$$

and the slowly changing amplitude envelope $a(t)$ means that

$$ \left| \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \log \big( a(t) \big) \right| \ll \omega_0 \ .$$

Then the output of such an LTI system is very well approximated as

$$ y(t) = \big| H(i \omega_0) \big| \ a(t - \tau_\text{g}(\omega_0)) \cos \big( \omega_0 (t - \tau_\phi(\omega_0)) + \theta \big) \; .$$

Here $\tau_\text{g}(\omega_0)$ and $\tau_\phi(\omega_0)$, the **group delay** and **phase delay** respectively, are given by the expressions below (and potentially are functions of the angular frequency $ \omega_0$).  The sinusoid, as indicated by the zero crossings, is delayed in time by phase delay, $\tau_\phi(\omega_0)$.  The envelope of the sinusoid is delayed in time by the group delay, $\tau_\text{g}(\omega_0)$.

In a linear phase system (with non-inverting gain), both $\tau_\text{g}$ and $\tau_\phi$ are constant (i.e. independent of frequency $\omega$) and equal, and their common value equals the overall delay of the system; and the unwrapped phase shift of the system (namely $-\omega \tau_\phi$) is negative, with magnitude increasing linearly with frequency $\omega$.

More generally, it can be shown that for an LTI system with transfer function $H(s)$ driven by a complex sinusoid of unit amplitude,

$$ x(t) = e^{i \omega t} $$

the output is

$$ \begin{align}
 y(t) & = H(i \omega) \ e^{i \omega t} \ \\
      & = \left( \big| H(i \omega) \big| e^{i \phi(\omega)} \right) \ e^{i \omega t} \ \\
      & = \big| H(i \omega) \big| \ e^{i \left(\omega t + \phi(\omega) \right)} \ \\
\end{align} \ $$

where the phase shift $\phi$ is

$$ \phi(\omega) \ \triangleq \arg \Big\{ H(i \omega) \Big\}  \;$$

Additionally, it can be shown that the group delay, $\tau_\text{g}$, and phase delay, $\tau_\phi$, are frequency-dependent, and they can be computed from the properly unwrapped phase shift $\phi$ by

$$\tau_\text{g}(\omega) = - \frac{\mathrm{d} \phi(\omega)}{\mathrm{d} \omega} = -\phi'(\omega) $$

$$ \tau_\phi(\omega) = - \frac{\phi(\omega)}{\omega} $$

**Proof** (sorta)

The Fourier Transform of

$$\begin{align}
x(t) &= a(t) \cos(\omega_0 t + \theta) \\
     &= a(t) \tfrac12 (e^{i(\omega_0 t + \theta)} + e^{-i(\omega_0 t + \theta)} ) \\
     &= \tfrac12 e^{-i\theta} a(t) e^{-i\omega_0 t} + \tfrac12 e^{i\theta} a(t) e^{i\omega_0 t} \\
\end{align}$$

is

$$ X(i\omega) = \tfrac12 e^{-i\theta} A\big(i(\omega+\omega_0)\big) + \tfrac12 e^{i\theta} A\big(i(\omega-\omega_0)\big) $$

where

$$ A(s)  =  \mathscr{L} \Big\{ a(t) \Big\} \ \triangleq \  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} a(t) e^{-st}\, \mathrm{d}t $$

The Fourier Transform of the output $y(t)$ is

$$\begin{align}
 Y(i\omega) &= H(i\omega) \cdot X(i\omega) \\
\\
  &= H(i\omega) \cdot \Big( \tfrac12 e^{-i\theta} A\big(i(\omega+\omega_0)\big) + \tfrac12 e^{i\theta} A\big(i(\omega-\omega_0)\big) \Big) \\
\\
  &= \tfrac12 H(i\omega) e^{-i\theta} A\big(i(\omega+\omega_0)\big) + \tfrac12  H(i\omega) e^{i\theta} A\big(i(\omega-\omega_0)\big)
\end{align} $$

Because $a(t)$ is slowly varying, that means that $A(i\omega)$ is bandlimited to much less than $\omega_0$.

$$ A(i\omega) \approx 0 \quad \text{unless} \ |\omega| \ll \omega_0 $$

That means the first term, $A\big(i(\omega+\omega_0)\big)$, is virtually zero except for $\omega \approx -\omega_0$ and the second term, $A\big(i(\omega-\omega_0)\big)$, is virtually zero except $\omega \approx +\omega_0$

The transfer function can be expressed in magnitude and phase form:

$$ H(i\omega) \triangleq |H(i\omega)| e^{i \phi(\omega)} $$

We know, for real $h(t)$ that $|H(-i\omega)| = |H(i\omega)|$ and $\phi(-\omega)=-\phi(\omega)$, and the derivative of phase $\phi'(-\omega)=\phi'(\omega)$.

Here we are approximating the phase function with the constant and first-order term of its Taylor series:

$$ \phi(\omega) \approx \phi(\omega_0) + \phi'(\omega_0)(\omega-\omega_0) \qquad \text{when} \ \omega \approx \omega_0 $$

$$ \phi(\omega) \approx \phi(-\omega_0) + \phi'(-\omega_0)(\omega+\omega_0) \qquad \text{when} \ \omega \approx -\omega_0 $$

Then in that narrow bandwidth the transfer function is approximated as

$$ H(i\omega) \big|_{\omega \approx \omega_0} \approx |H(i\omega_0)| e^{i (\phi(\omega_0) + \phi'(\omega_0)(\omega-\omega_0) )} $$

and similarly

$$\begin{align}
H(i\omega) \big|_{\omega \approx -\omega_0} &\approx |H(-i\omega_0)| e^{i (\phi(-\omega_0) + \phi'(-\omega_0)(\omega+\omega_0) )} \\
&=|H(i\omega_0)| e^{i (-\phi(\omega_0) + \phi'(\omega_0)(\omega+\omega_0) )} \\
\end{align}$$

Then

$$\begin{align}
Y(i\omega) &= \tfrac12 H(i\omega) e^{-i\theta} A\big(i(\omega+\omega_0)\big) + \tfrac12 H(i\omega) e^{i\theta} A\big(i(\omega-\omega_0)\big) \\
\\
 &\approx \tfrac12 |H(i\omega_0)| e^{i (-\phi(\omega_0) + \phi'(\omega_0)(\omega+\omega_0) )} e^{-i\theta} A\big(i(\omega+\omega_0)\big) \\
 & \qquad + \tfrac12 |H(i\omega_0)| e^{i (\phi(\omega_0) + \phi'(\omega_0)(\omega-\omega_0) )} e^{i\theta} A\big(i(\omega-\omega_0)\big) \\
\\
 &= \tfrac12 |H(i\omega_0)| e^{\phi'(\omega_0)\omega} \Big( e^{i (-\phi(\omega_0) + \phi'(\omega_0)\omega_0 )} e^{-i\theta} A\big(i(\omega+\omega_0)\big) \\
 & \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad + \ e^{i (\phi(\omega_0) - \phi'(\omega_0)\omega_0 )} e^{i\theta} A\big(i(\omega-\omega_0)\big) \Big) \\
\\
 &= e^{\phi'(\omega_0)\omega} \ \tilde{Y}(i\omega) \\
\end{align}$$

where

$$ \tilde{Y}(i\omega) = \tfrac12 |H(i\omega_0)| \Big(e^{i (-\phi(\omega_0) + \phi'(\omega_0)\omega_0 )} e^{-i\theta} A\big(i(\omega+\omega_0)\big) \\ \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad + \ e^{i (\phi(\omega_0) - \phi'(\omega_0)\omega_0 )} e^{i\theta} A\big(i(\omega-\omega_0)\big) \Big)$$

The inverse Fourier Transform of $\tilde{Y}(i\omega)$ is

$$\begin{align}
 \tilde{y}(t) &= \tfrac12 |H(i\omega_0)| \Big(e^{i (-\phi(\omega_0) + \phi'(\omega_0)\omega_0 )} e^{-i\theta} e^{-i\omega_0 t} a(t) + e^{i (\phi(\omega_0) - \phi'(\omega_0)\omega_0 )} e^{i\theta} e^{i\omega_0 t} a(t) \Big) \\
\\
 &= |H(i\omega_0)| \ a(t) \ \tfrac12 \Big(e^{-i (\omega_0 t + \phi(\omega_0) - \phi'(\omega_0)\omega_0 + \theta)} + e^{i (\omega_0 t + \phi(\omega_0) - \phi'(\omega_0)\omega_0 + \theta)} \Big) \\
\\
 &= |H(i\omega_0)| \ a(t) \ \cos\big(\omega_0 t + \phi(\omega_0) - \phi'(\omega_0)\omega_0 + \theta \big) \\
\end{align}$$

Now multiplying $\tilde{Y}(i\omega)$ by $e^{\phi'(\omega_0)\omega}$ causes, in the time domain, $\tilde{y}(t)$ to be **advanced** in time by $\phi'(\omega_0)$.  So

$$\begin{align}
 y(t) &= \tilde{y}\big(t+\phi'(\omega_0)\big) \\
\\
 &= |H(i\omega_0)| \ a(t+\phi'(\omega_0)) \ \cos \big(\omega_0 (t+\phi'(\omega_0)) + \phi(\omega_0) - \phi'(\omega_0)\omega_0 + \theta \big) \\
\\
 &= |H(i\omega_0)| \ a(t+\phi'(\omega_0)) \ \cos\big(\omega_0 t + \phi(\omega_0) + \theta \big) \\
\\
 &= |H(i\omega_0)| \ a(t-\tau_\text{g}(\omega_0)) \ \cos\big(\omega_0 (t-\tau_\phi(\omega_0)) + \theta \big) \\
\end{align}$$

Where group delay $\tau_\text{g}(\omega)$ and phase delay $\tau_\phi(\omega)$ are defined as above.

Comment: For those flagging this answer as a copy from Wikipedia, this poster, rb-j, [wrote the original mathematical version of the Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Group_delay_and_phase_delay&diff=111730465&oldid=99474214)

Comment: Wow! @PeterK. you found that out!!  This was right before Wikipedia kicked my butt outa there.  (I have done many edits since as an anonymous IP.)  It's been 15 years since User:Rbj was legitimately editing Wikipedia.

Comment: Ya. I figured it wouldn't take too long to validate my belief that you wrote the Wikipedia page. And I wanted to let the netcops know there was a very good reason for the repetition here.

Comment: i see a couple of errors.  i gotta fix it.

Comment: y wiki boot rbj

Comment: You can go to my [talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Rbj) and press the [View history](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=User_talk:Rbj&action=history) button and read.  Long story.

Answer (score 0):

It stems from the definition of the Laplace/fourier transforms using $e^{-st}$ or $e^{-j\omega t}$.  This can be checked intuitively by looking at the transform pair of a delayed impulse, compare the time domain delay to the frequency domain phase.  If you modified the transform to use $e^{+st}$instead, it would be the other way round.